# Can not start Mongo node

Tags: mongodb

Trying to start mongo node with command

```
mongos --configdb 192.168.6.3:27019 --port 27018
```

In results having output:

```
Tue Mar 15 16:08:21.062 [mongosMain] warning:  couldn't check dbhash on config server 192.168.6.3:27019 :: caused by :: 11002 socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] server [192.168.6.3:27019] mongos connectionpool error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.6.3:27019
Tue Mar 15 16:08:21.064 [mongosMain] ERROR: error upgrading config database to v4 :: caused by :: could not load config version for upgrade :: caused by :: 11002 socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] server [192.168.6.3:27019] mongos connectionpool error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.6.3:27019
Tue Mar 15 16:08:21.064 warning:  couldn't check dbhash on config server 192.168.6.3:27019 :: caused by :: 11002 socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] server [192.168.6.3:27019] mongos connectionpool error: couldn't connect to server 192.168.6.3:27019
```

Could you help me, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: f7f74fab-8ebb-4266-89a5-2bf63401a379 is your host name?

Comment: @EricPro Mongos starts mongo shard routing service. I think you want to start Mongo server, if so, use `mongod` command instead.

Comment: yeah it is host name @EvgenyS.

Comment: @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu, trying to start especially route node.

Comment: @EricPro Looking at the exception `can't resolve DNS for [f7f74fab-8ebb-4266-89a5-2bf63401a379]` Is `f7f74fab-8ebb-4266-89a5-2bf63401a379` the hostname and are you able to ping `f7f74fab-8ebb-4266-89a5-2bf63401a379`. if not, can you try with IP address of the host `f7f74fab-8ebb-4266-89a5-2bf63401a379` assuming you would be able to ping with IP address.

Comment: Then there is no DNS record in your DNS lookup table. You should either edit /etc/hosts or add required record in your DNS zone on your DNS server.

Comment: can not ping with hostname, but with ip it is ok @MadhusudanaReddySunnapu

Comment: @EricPro So you can try the above `mongos` command with the `ipaddress` instead of `hostname` or if you want to continue with hostname, update your hosts file to map this `f7f74fab-8ebb-4266-89a5-2bf63401a379` to the `ipaddress`.

Comment: tried to put ipaddress instead of hostname, now have another exception will update question.

Comment: The message is self explaining - mongos can't connect to config server. Either there is no config db instance running on that IP:port or firewall settings do not allow your mongos to connect to that instance.

Comment: yeap, I forgot to start that node, seems it is working. thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would summarize solution from the comments to close the question.

First, read the mongo server logs.

If you see DNS-related errors there then check if you use correct DNS names which your system can resolve. To exclude DNS errors try to run server using direct IP addresses in configurtaion.

If you still see network-related errors (such as could not connect to server) then check:

- the server instance you are trying to connect to is running
- you use correct IP address and port
- your network links are up
- firewalls both on peer and your side are not blocking connection